# how to play samba Share filepath through android media player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

my samba Share file path is : smb://10.0.0.18/MZAES_Songs/Aashiqui 2/Asan Nahin Yahan.mp3

How can I give this path to android mediaPlayer?

For example for local memory file can be played as

```
String filepath = "sdcard/emulated/0/ashqui/asaa.mp3";
mediaplayer.setDataSource(filePath");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

etc..

But how to do with samba shared file path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Media Player can't play samba share files( as per my knowledge ). So you have to select another way to play those files.
I had solved this problem in this way,
By using NanoHttpClient( 3rd party API ). This API(library jar file), you can get it from Google search.
Download and integrate it to your project.
Then serve your smb file on your device only. 
And give that path to your Media Player( http link ). Hope i have answered well.

Comment: can you give any examples

Comment: Sorry.. for now i don't have any examples.